# Cmder Git PhpStorm - консоль многострочный ввод не даёт

Tags: git, phpstorm

Столкнулся с чудом — связка Cmder + Git + PhpStorm - консоль многострочный ввод не даёт  (`git commit -m "Test` + Enter делает новый коммит, а не новую строку ввода). В остальном всё работает нормально. Сама консоль Cmder нормально даёт многострочный ввод делать.

PhpStorm почти не настроен. Git у него подключен. Отдельно Git не ставился, тянется из полной версии Cmder.

> git version 2.29.1.windows.1, PhpStorm - 2021.1.4 x64

Пробовал различные варианты, встреченные в интернет: через одинарные кавычки, символ доллара и т.п. — ничто не помогло. Прошу подсказать решение, а также, желательно, причину проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему указанием в Terminal -> Shell Path `""cmd" /k ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\git-for-windows\bin\bash.exe""`. Ранее пытался там активироваться батником `""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat`

Таким образом, есть решение, но оно частичное, позволяющее не топтаться на месте, и не даёт ответа на вопрос о причинах проблемы, что так же интересно мне.

Через батник активироваться эффективнее, за счёт возможности прописывания в нём много чего сопутствующего. Поэтому, если кто-то знаете решение при сохранении активации через батник, милости просим.

Ап: тут https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-IntelliJ-based-Integration показан официальный пример подключения через батник, одно он так же ведёт к этой проблеме.